# How to make a alerting system in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, alert

I'm working in a projet (PHP-MySQL) that i need to desing a alerting system, i know that asking how to do it is not a good question, but i will try to put how i thinking to do it and see if some people can add other ideas and advices.

So i need a system of alerting for this conditions:

1. If the code php is not working fine (communication error, php error, any error type...)
2. If some value change (the comparison will be made by a références value; if the X value is empty...)
3. Have the possibility to make a selection of alerting made to send this to another system use in the enterprise (they have to treat the more importat, and if not, not have this information in this one system)

**Point 2 and 3:**

My first approach was thinking to makes triggers in the database, use some filter in the trigger, and put it in one table of alerting/log, have a cron job in php that see/search the newest rows and execute a function that will call the enterprise service for send only the importat information, BUT after make a research in internet use the triggers is not recommended, the people said that the trigger/php approach is not maintainable,

***The question :***

any one have already do this can of logic? What can be one better way of doing this? How to see if some value change. (without fetching the database add comparing result with the newest)

***For the point 1:***

i'm thinking to use one hooks approach, because the flexibility of addapt the code to the needs of the enterprise, (the projet is a fork of one github projet) The idea is that not all people going to have the same needs, so having a hooks approach, any person can add the function to the hook and see the problem if the are.

***The question :***

The hooks option in the view performace is a good idea? Other better idea?

Another part is how to use a queue/logic for send this alerting values to the enterprise system? i sow RabbitMQ but i'm not sure about if this can be used in the projet? And if they are another system for doing this?

For the last part, the are library for make a easy alerting system in PHP?

Comment: o_o a simple Ajax Javascript called from time to time in automatic inside your page won't do eh...

Comment: The code is a very php approach, and is a service that get information from different source, this information is get every 5h and stored in in mysql, so i have one cron job that search/fetch the sources, is at this moment that i need the (alerting system | error system)

Comment: I'm putting it on the fly ;). If you've got a "service" that store those Alert on Db. You can run each n (n is a var eh) seconds an Ajax Call to a page that will search this db zone. That will create a basic Alert Messaging system.